# How do I show loading indicator in WebView Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I want to show the loading indicator while the webpage for my WebView is loading. Here is my code:

```
class Dates extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dates({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final Set<Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>> gestureRecognizers = {
  Factory(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())
};

UniqueKey _key = UniqueKey();

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    
      home: WebView(
        initialUrl: "https://www.allendalecolumbia.org/calendar",
        gestureRecognizers: gestureRecognizers,
        
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in future builder and return loading widget until the page received http 200 or is fully loaded.

More information about using future builder and returning different widgets until action has been completed can be [found here](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-futurebuilder-widget-examples).

Answer (score -1):

To make a Loading indicator on **Webview**, you can use a boolean function and webView widgets **onPageFinished** function to do the loading...

Use a Stateful widget.

**Here is the complete code:**

```
 class Dates extends State< Dates >{

  
  bool isLoading=true;
  final _key = UniqueKey();
  
  const Dates({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  final Set<Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>> gestureRecognizers = 
       { Factory(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())};

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            key: _key,
            initialUrl: "https://www.allendalecolumbia.org/calendar",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            gestureRecognizers: gestureRecognizers,
            onPageFinished: (finish) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          isLoading ? Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
                    : Stack(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

First define variable like this:

```
bool isLoading = true;
```

then do this:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    WebView(
      onPageFinished: (finish) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      },
    ),
    isLoading
        ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : SizedBox(),
  ],
)
```

**Note**: you need to do this in a `StatefulWidget` in order to works.
If you don't want to use `StatefulWidget`, you can use `StatefulBuilder` widget like this:

```
class Dates extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dates({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isLoading = true;
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            WebView(
              onPageFinished: (finish) {
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              },
            ),
            isLoading
                ? Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : SizedBox(),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```